# Alternative for interfaces for communication between components

Tags: java, android

I would like to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` but my code structure is a mess and I cannot get my way around it. I have a fragment, a custom dialog class, and MainActivity.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Fragment is created here along with 3 other fragments. Dialog is also created here

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        fragment = new FragmentHome();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        loadCustomActionBar("Home", false);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_foods:
                        fragment = new FragmentFood();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        loadCustomActionBar("Foods", true);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_drinks:
                        fragment = new FragmentDrink();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        loadCustomActionBar("Beverages", true);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_cart:
                        fragment = new FragmentCart();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        loadCustomActionBar("Cart", false);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

private void loadCustomActionBar(String titleTxt, boolean bool) {
        CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog()
         .....
    }
```

**CustomDialog**

```
CustomDialog is responsible for updating database. 
I want to call notifyDataSetChanged() here after updating database to update view as well.

Button addItem = .....
addItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick() {
         dialog.show();
    }
});
```

**Fragment.java**

```
ListAdapter is located here
```

I have tried using interfaces, but either I did it wrong or it doesn't work. Kindly help please. What are other alternatives for interfaces?

EDIT : 
It seems you do not get my problem. I JUST WANT TO ACCESS THE LISTADAPTER CONTAINED IN THE FRAGMENT FROM MY CUSTOM DIALOG, PEOPLE OF THIS SITE.

Comment: So in short you want the fragment to update it's view when the CustomDialog changes the data in the db?

Comment: Yea that's it....

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you have a variable *fragment*. For your case you can define some BaseFragment class in which you will have abstract method datasetChanged(). All your separate fragments will be derivatives of BaseFragment and your variable *fragment* will be of type BaseFragment. Derivative fragments will implement function datasetChanged() in which they will call notifyDatasetChanged for their own adapters.

Then you can have a callback in your CustomDialog which will call datasetChanged of your variable *fragment*.

```
class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    abstract void datasetChanged();
    ...
}


class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
    ...
    var notifyCallback: Function;
    public setCallback(Function callback) {
        notifyCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

Then when you will create CustomDialog just set the callback to your fragments method datasetChanged():

```
customDialog.setCallback(fragment::datasetChanged());
```

After that, when your customDialog will need to notify for updates it will call for callback function.

```
notifyCallback.apply()
```

Comment: Really? Let me know when you will find your silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to achieve this

1. Send the instance of the fragment to the CustomDialog like `CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(fragment)`. Now that the CustomDialog has the reference to the fragment you can call a method in the fragment that would fetch the new data from the db and update it's views
2. Use EventBus library. You would register the Fragment as a listener to EventBus and implement `onEventMainThread(YourEventName event)`.And the CustomDialog would post the YourEventName event to the EventBus after it updates the db. The EventBus will deliver this event to the fragment since it is registered to listen to YourEventName
3. Try to refresh the views in the onResume of the fragment. This would work in the case where the dialog and fragment are not accessible simultaneously

Comment: Your no.1 would not work. I have 4 fragments, all of which are different. Your no. 3 is my problem, view is updated only when I change tabs. I am not familiar with your no.2

Comment: So you want to update all the 4 fragments from one custom dialog?

Comment: Yes one dialog. But update all the 4 fragments. Correct?

Comment: No, just one fragment

Comment: Then I don't see any problem with solution 1. After assigning fragment to a new custom fragment you are calling loadCustomActionBar which creates a new CustomDialog. So every time you call loadCustomActionBar there is going to be a new CustomDialog that holds the reference to the current fragment

Comment: and? yea dialog has reference to fragment, but does dialog know which fragment? No. Genius.